# Bootstrap 3 jumbotron not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made some changes to my code and now I cannot figure out what I did wrong, but now my Bootstrap 3 `jumbotron` is completely off. I don't know why but my HTML files also keep getting corrupted, losing any work I spent hours on. I have notepad++ and atom and I use both I'm guessing that may be the problem.

How do I get my `jumbotron` working again like I had it before and what caused it to mess up?

My HTML code after I changed it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
      <html lang="en-US">
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <!-- jQuery library -->
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
         <link href="designstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> <!-- creating a black navbar-->
   <!-- this container class keeps things contained, brand will stay at top-->
   <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Cryptocurrency Guidance</a>
   <!--button-->  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
   <!-- three spans for bars stacked on eachother for hamburger icon-->
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <!--closing div for navbar-header-->
   </div>
   <!-- starting div for the navbar to collapse-->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> <!--target-->
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <!-- sets styling and pos to right -->
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="guide.html">My Bitcoin Guide</a></li> <!-- link guide html page here -->
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media<b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div> <!-- container ending div closing-->
   </div> <!--  starting nav bar div closing-->
   <div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron text-center">
   <div class="page-header">
   <h1>Bitcoin</h1>
   </div>
   <p>A peer to peer electronic <span class="importance">cash</span> system</p>
   <a href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf" class="btn btn-default">Read whitepaper</a>
   <a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container"> <!-- starting carousel container -->
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active">
   <img src="bitcoinwhitepaper.jpg" alt="bitcoin" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
   <img src="bitcoin.jpg" alt="bitcoinwhitepaper" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
   <img src="blockchain.png" alt="blockchain" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>  <!-- ending carousel container -->
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="aligncolumn">
   <!-- thumbnail -->
   <div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class = "thumbnail">
   <img src = "300x200.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
   </div>
   <div class = "caption">
   <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
   <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
   <p>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class = "thumbnail">
   <img src = "300x200.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
   </div>
   <div class = "caption">
   <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
   <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
   <p>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class = "thumbnail">
   <img src = "300x200.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
   </div>
   <div class = "caption">
   <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
   <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
   <p>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role =" button">
   Button
   </a>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class = "thumbnail">
   <img src = "300x200.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
   </div>
   <div class = "caption">
   <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
   <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
   <p>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">
   Button
   </a>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <!-- navbar navbar default navbar-fixed-bottom footer-->
   <div class="footer">
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <div class="container">
   <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site build by Chris R</p>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_4p45CXlEXSYaPMIF80QlA?view_as=subscriber" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

My HTML code before I changed it that works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="designstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"> <!-- creating a black navbar-->
    <!-- this container class keeps things contained, brand will stay at top-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Enthusiastic Builds</a>
      <!--button-->  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
           <!-- three spans for bars stacked on eachother for hamburger icon-->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
        <!--closing div for navbar-header-->
        </div>
         <!-- starting div for the navbar to collapse-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> <!--target-->

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <!-- sets styling and pos to right -->
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>


              </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>



          </ul>

        </div>


      </div> <!-- container ending div closing-->

  </div> <!--  starting nav bar div closing-->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Gaming Build</h1>
    </div>
      <p>Build the <span class="importance">ultimate</span> quality gaming budget build.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Watch now</a>
      <a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dumby Text</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="chicago.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <h3><a href="#">Loren Ipsum</a></h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- navbar navbar default navbar-fixed-bottom footer-->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

<div class="container">
  <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site build by Chris</p>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on You-Tube</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a tool called [split diff link](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff) for atom - it sounds like a perfect tool for this type of issue. I use it when I need to compare the differences between two files.

[before](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_3_jumbotron)
[after](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_3_jumbotron_full_width)

From what I can tell - it appears the jumbotron appears to be working.

- It could be that other parts are effecting the page?
- maybe the css isnt rendered?
- maybe there is an issue with the javascript?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would be nice if answer doesn't contain new questions, surely you can improve your answer and help